# JavaScript: Variable to replace a key in an object needed by a method in DHX is not working

Tags: javascript, object, variables

I have been at this for over an hour and I am getting nowhere. I need to use a variable containing a string literal to replace a key in an Object for a DHX method, but it does not work.

When I place the 'actual' string into the method, it works perfectly. Here is what works ('col5' is the key in the object):

```
grid.data.update(2, {col5: 1} );
```

But ... if I now introduce a variable containing the same string literal, it fails (does not update the grid). This *does not* work:

```
let x = "col5"
grid.data.update(2, {x: 1} );
```

When I view this variable in *console.log*, it shows up perfectly. I even tried *JSON.stringify* to see if it needed to be converted, but that did not work either.

I'm looking for a way to use a variable in place of a key in this object.

Comment: you want `{ [x]: 1 }`

Comment: @Pointy lol, that was fast. I was writing an answer ;-;

Comment: Seriously? It was that easy? I tried so many things found on SO but not that. BRILLIANT! Thank you! Could I ask - as a newby - what do you officially call this approach so I know what to search for next time?

Comment: @LightningMcQueen there's a duplicate or three out there somewhere.

Comment: @ND_Coder it's usually called "computed property names". See for example [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#computed_property_names)

Comment: @RobinZigmond. Just read your link. VERY helpful. Thank you. I think my biggest struggle with SO is not knowing what something is called to perform a quality search. I'm sure all the answers are out there if I just ask the right question!!!

Comment: Hey @Pointy, could you make your comment into a full answer - since it appears to have solved OP's question?